# Singular Integrals in Scattering Theory

Tags: scattering, integration, complex-numbers

This might seem a bit off-topic question but it comes into different physical theories. While learning quantum scattering I came across certain singular integrals but could not compute them. I am learning to compute singular integrals using the '$i\epsilon$-prescription' of complex contour integration from the book Mathematical Physics by V. Balakrishnan (Chapter 23, Article 23.3.4). Following the book, the integral I want to compute is,

> $$f(x_0)=\displaystyle{\int_a^b dx\frac{\phi (x)}{x-x_0}}\tag{1}$$ where $a < x_0 < b$ are real numbers, $\phi(x)$ is a sufficiently smooth function, and $\phi(x_0)\neq 0$. The integrand obviously diverges at $x = x_0$ because of the factor $(x − x_0)$ in the denominator. As it stands, the Riemann integral in Eq.(1) does not exist, because of this nonintegrable singularity of the integrand. Suppose, however, we move the singularity away from the path of integration by giving it either a positive
>   imaginary part $+i\epsilon$ (where $\epsilon > 0$), or a negative imaginary part $−i\epsilon$. This step, called an $i\epsilon$-prescription, makes the original integral well-defined. The integrals in the two cases are given, respectively, by $$f(x_0 ± i\epsilon) = \int_a^b dx \frac{\phi(x)}{x−(x_0±i\epsilon)} = \int_a^b dx\frac{\phi(x)}{x−x_0∓i\epsilon}\tag{2}$$ 
>   The question is: what happens as $\epsilon \to 0$ ? We can continue to keep the integral well-defined by distorting the path of integration away from the approaching singularity, to form a small semicircle of radius $\epsilon$. **This semicircle lies in the lower half-plane in the case of $\boldsymbol{f(x_0+i\epsilon)}$, and in the upper half-plane in the case of $\boldsymbol{f(x_0 − i\epsilon)}$**. This is shown in figures (a) and (b) :
>   [image]
>   On the small semicircles, the variable of integration is $z = x_0 + \epsilon e^{i\theta}$, so that $dz =\epsilon e^{i\theta}id\theta$. The argument $\theta$ runs from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ in the case of $f (x + i\epsilon)$, and from $\pi$ to $0$ in the case of $f (x − i\epsilon)$. Taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ then yields the Cauchy principal value integral from $a$ to $b$, plus the contribution from the semicircle: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_a^b dx\frac{\phi(x)}{x−x_0∓i\epsilon}= P\int_a^b dx\frac{\phi(x)}{x-x_0}± i\pi\phi(x_0)\tag{3}$$

I have two questions :

Firstly, I do not understand the line in bold. Why the semicircle lies in the lower half-plane in the case of $f(x_0+i\epsilon)$, and in the upper half-plane in the case of $f(x_0 − i\epsilon)$ ?

Secondly, when I am computing the contribution from the semi-circle, I do not get the value $i\pi\phi(x_0)$ . This is how I am doing it for $f(x_0+i\epsilon)$ : $$\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}dz\frac{\phi(z)}{z-x_0-i\epsilon}&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} d\theta \,\,\epsilon e^{i\theta}i\frac{\phi(x_0+\epsilon e^{i\theta})}{\epsilon (e^{i\theta}-i)}=i\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} d\theta \,\, e^{i\theta}\frac{\phi(x_0+\epsilon e^{i\theta})}{(e^{i\theta}-i)}\\
&=i\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\left[\phi(x_0+\epsilon e^{i\theta})\int d\theta\frac{e^{i\theta}}{(e^{i\theta}-i)}\right]_{\pi}^{2\pi}-\epsilon\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} d\theta \,\left\{\frac{d\phi(x_0+\epsilon e^{i\theta})}{d\theta}\int d\theta \frac{e^{i\theta}}{(e^{i\theta}-i)}\right\}\right)
\end{align} $$

The second term vanishes by the application of the limit. Then, $$\begin{align}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}dz\frac{\phi(z)}{z-x_0-i\epsilon}&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\left[\phi(x_0+\epsilon e^{i\theta})\ln{(e^{i\theta}-i)}\right]_{\pi}^{2\pi}\right)\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\phi(x_0+\epsilon e^{i\theta})\ln{\left(\frac{1-i}{-1-i}\right)}\right)\\
&=\phi(x_0)\ln{\left(\frac{i-1}{i+1}\right)}\\
&=\phi(x_0)\ln{\left(\frac{{(i-1)}^2}{-2}\right)}\\
&=\phi(x_0)\ln{i}\\
&=\phi(x_0)\ln{e^{i\pi/2}}\\
&=i\frac{\pi}{2}\phi(x_0)
\end{align}$$
So, a factor of 2 is coming in the denominator which should not be there. Where am I getting wrong? I had initially posted this question on Mathematics SE but no one answered. Please help.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3699357/11127

Comment: You can skip a lot of steps if you know Jordan's lemma (this explains the upper/lower halfs thing) and complex integration methods. These are very well synthesized in "Mathematical Methods for Physicists" by Arfken.

Comment: Thank you @JuanC97 . I will definitely look in that. But I still want to know what am I doing wrong in this process.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question partly because it seems to be pure math, and partly because it was crossposted.